# Wcf returns data inside DataSet property and returns other properties as null

Tags: wcf, serialization, datacontract

I have WCF service returns the following DataContract:

```
[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    public DataSet DS { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

And inside the GetEmployee service, I am returning Employee object but the value of all columns are returned as null except DS property which contains the values of Employee properties inside Nodes list.

```
public Employee GetEmployee()
    {
            return new Employee
            {
                ID = "76072",
                Name = "name",
                Email = "emp@test.com",
                DS = null
            };
    }
```

But If I remove DS property from Employee DataContract it returns data inside properties correctly.

My question is why WCF returns data inside DataSet property implicitly?

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using a dataset object as property to be passed in WCF. It is a huge load on WCF. While this might not exactly answer your question, Scott Hanselman backs me up on this: [Returning Datasets in webservices is the Spawn of Satan](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx)

Comment: I know that but it's a legacy service I am forced to integrate with it

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by assigning new Dataset() object instead of null like the following :

```
public Employee GetEmployee()
{
        return new Employee
        {
            ID = "76072",
            Name = "name",
            Email = "emp@test.com",
            DS = new DataSet()
        };
}
```

Now in the client of the WCF service Employee's properties are mapped correctly instead of returning them inside DS property.

Answer (score 0):

Did I misunderstand your question or where I lost the configuration? I could not reproduce your problem referring to your steps. On my side. the client could receive correct values normally. I suggest you add the namespace to the datacontract.
Here is my demo, wish it is useful to you.
**Server(IP: 10.157.13.69)**

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService)))
            {
                sh.Opened += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("service is ready...");
                };
                sh.Closed += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is closed");
                };
                sh.Open();
                Console.ReadLine();
                sh.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Product SayHello();
    } 
    public class MyService : IService
    {
        public Product SayHello()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
            dt.Rows.Add(10, "Lemon");
            dt.Rows.Add(11, "Peach");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            return new Product()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Apple",
                DS = ds
            };
        }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace ="MyCorporation")]
     public class Product
    {
        [DataMember]
        public DataSet DS { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**App.config(server)**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Server6.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="mybeh">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Server6.IService" >
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:13060"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mybeh">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"></serviceMetadata>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Client.**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
            try
            {
                var result = client.SayHello();
                var r2 = result.DS.Tables[0];
                Console.WriteLine($"{result.Id},{result.Name}");
                Console.WriteLine($"{r2.Rows[0][0]},{r2.Rows[0][1]}\n{r2.Rows[1][0]},{r2.Rows[1][1]}");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }
}
```

**App.config(client).**

```
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://10.157.13.69:13060/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
        </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Result.**
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.